# How to connect two android devices for transfer of sensor data(Multiplayer Gaming)

Tags: android

I want to connect two android devices(ie 2 mobiles) such that I use sensor in one phone, and data about its position and rotational changes are send to 2nd mobile, so that I can use that to move some object in this 2nd mobile accordingly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google Play Game Services? Bluetooth? WiFi Direct?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use Google Play Game Services Nearby Connections:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/nearby